# How to style react native for multiple different devices and operating systems

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am relatively new to react native and am not looking for actual code however I am wondering the best way to implement layouts/ styling of a page so that it looks the same proportion wise across multiple different devices and operating systems. For example iPhone X through to 13 have different size screens and then if you include the new Samsung's, Google Pixels and Huawei phones there is a lot of different sizes of screens.
I can create different styles by detecting what device is being used and getting the logical resolution from that however I am wondering if there is a better way than just doing this for 10 different phone sizes. For example in the picture you can see the front wheel of the car is on the edge of the blue box which gives it an almost 3D effect.[[image]] To get this effect across 2 different devices I have to change the absolute positioning of the car for both devices however the more screen sizes/ devices I want it to look the same on the more code it is and it seems like I am using a long winded/ redundant method.

Another alternative I have thought about is just turning that section into an image and using it as a background image however I am not sure how that will affect performance.

Any thoughts?

Comment: amazing how nobody replied. I am also new to RN, but I am a seasoned web developer. On the web we have principles like "mobile first" approach, for instance, that frames from the smallest to the bigger screen sizes. 

I am learning RN on the fly and I ask myself which principles are used for different devices as well.